# Centering a div overlay

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to center a div that overlays the entire image. I have a jQuery script that is suppose to check the size of the document (width and height), divide it, and set the div's width. Which I believe should center the contents in the middle of the page.

```
<head>  
    <style type="text/css">
        .boxWrapper{
            min-width:640px;
            min-height:480px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            vertical-align:center;
            padding: 15px 10px 10px 30px;
            z-index:8;
        }
        .box {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            vertical-align:center;
            z-index:8;
        }
        .blackOut {
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index: 5;
            width:100%;
            height:100%; 
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
    <div class="pageWrapper">   
    <div class="binShadow">
        <div class="bin">       
            <table id="tableBin" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>location</th>
                    <th>duration</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='A001C010_111129_R1VL.mov'>A001C010_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
                        <td>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, leo non.</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="A001C011_111129_R1VL.mov">A001C011_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>
    $("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = $(this).attr("href");
     var overlay = jQuery('<div class="blackOut"><div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box"><video src="'+url+'" /></video></div></div></div>');
     var left = "width:"+width($document)/2+"px";
     var top = "hieght:"+hieght($document)/2+"px";
     ​
     $('</span>').text(data).css('width', left).appendTo('#boxWrapper');
     $('</span>').text(data).css('height', top).appendTo('#boxWrapper');
     overlay.appendTo(document.body);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: change `width($document)` to --> `$(document).width()`

Comment: Made the change, but still not working. Hrmmm

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll gite it a try. Just tell me... what element should appear in the middle of the page?

Comment: boxWrapper is inside box. So I'm assuming if boxWrapper is centered box would follow. If not than just box. I probably have one too many divs now anyway.

Comment: Setting `height` and `width` on the `span` elements won't work unless they are set to `display: block`

Comment: There you go. Take a look and lemme know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No much need for jQuery. Pure CSS.

http://jsbin.com/ebuyet/edit#javascript,html,live

The jQuery:

```
$("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var url = $(this).attr("href");
     var overlay = '<div class="blackOut"> <span class="boxWrapper"> <div class="box">  <video src='+url+'></video>  </div></span></div>';

     $('body').append(overlay);
     $('.blackOut').stop().fadeTo(1000,1); // fadeIn after is appended
});
```

The CSS:

```
    .blackOut {
        position: absolute;

        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        z-index: 5;
        width:100%;
        height:100%; 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        text-align:center;
    }
     span.boxWrapper{
display:block;
        width:640px;
        height:480px;
margin:0 auto;
        padding: 15px 10px 10px 30px;
        z-index:8;
        background:#eee;
    }
    .box {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        vertical-align:center;
        z-index:8;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/spw6K/53/

```
<head>  
    <style type="text/css">
        .boxWrapper{
            min-width:640px;
            min-height:480px;
            text-align:center;
            z-index:8;
            height:100%;
        }
        .box {
            z-index:8;
            height:100%;
        }
        .blackOut {
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index: 5;
            width:100%;
            height:100%; 
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
    <div class="pageWrapper">

    <div class="binShadow">
        <div class="bin">       
            <table id="tableBin" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>location</th>
                    <th>duration</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='A001C010_111129_R1VL.mov'>A001C010_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
                        <td>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, leo non.</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="A001C011_111129_R1VL.mov">A001C011_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="A001C012_111129_R1VL.mov">A001C012_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
                        <td>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, leo non.</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>
    $("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var top = "padding-top:" + $(window).height() / 2 + "px";

        var overlay = jQuery('<div class="blackOut"><div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box" style="' + top + '"><video class="videoBox" src="'+url+'"/></div></div></div>');

        $("body").append( overlay );
    });
</script>​
```

Comment: A link with no explanation isn't much of an answer. But even if it were: the fiddle in question does not show a div overlay that is centered in both directions on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want some text centered below your video, you don't need to use jQuery for the positioning.  Plus, you had a number of issues with your code:

1) You need to use `$(document).width()` or `$(window).width()`, not `width($(document))`

2) You seem to be adding the same data twice:

```
$('</span>').text(data).css('width', left).appendTo('#boxWrapper');
$('</span>').text(data).css('height', top).appendTo('#boxWrapper');
```

This adds two spans.  I think you want one span with both css attributes (and you should use `top` and `left` if you are positioning, not `height`/`width`:

```
$('</span>').text(data).css({'left': left, 'top': top}).appendTo('#boxWrapper');
```

3) You are trying to append to `boxWrapper` as an ID, but you are using `boxWrapper` as a class: `.appendTo('#boxWrapper');` => `.appendTo('.boxWrapper');`

4) You are trying to append to `boxWrapper` before it is added to the page.  To use a selector, it must exist in the DOM.  You need to add the `boxWrapper` first, or add the data in the HTML of `boxWrapper`.

That being said, if you data is truly text as is implied, use CSS text centering. I would add your data in a `div`, and then make it 100% width with `text-align: center`.

```
$("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var overlay = $('<div class="blackOut"><div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box video">Video Here: '+url+'</div></div></div>');

    // You need to add the overlay to your DOM before you can append your data to it
    overlay.appendTo('body'); 

    // Now you can append your data to the boxWrapper
    $('<div class="data">').text("This is where your data would go").appendTo('.boxWrapper');
});
```

CSS:

```
.data {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Ead7r/2/